# Adding SSH Key to GitHub and getting a message "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access"

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm trying to add the SSH Key to GitHub and getting a message "You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access"

Is this a correct way of setting things up? If not how can this be resolved please?

Answer (score 1):

You've done it correctly, but misunderstood the purpose of the SSH key.

Its purpose is to allow **authenticated** pull and push using a git client. Writing any repo with `git push` always needs to be authenticated, and an SSH key makes the authentication *easy to automate*. Cloning or otherwise reading a **private** repo also requires authentication, and the SSH key makes it easy to authenticate *automatically* when you `git clone`, `git fetch`, etc.

As the error message shows, its purpose is not to give you a shell account, where you can execute arbitrary commands (which is what SSH is commonly used for).

The purpose of the SSH key is to allow easy *automation* of those *git operations* which require *authentication*.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing at a lot of what you've done (please provide details next time), but it sounds like the following:

1. You successfully created an SSH keypair
2. You added the public key to GitHub
3. You ran `ssh git@github.com` (maybe with some flags)

If that's the case, then you've set up SSH authentication, and you've confirmed that everything is working exactly as it's supposed to. As the message says, GitHub does not provide shell access; you can use the SSH key you set up with commands like `git clone`, `git pull`, `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git ls-remote`.

Comment: Thank you. I will provide more detals next time.